# Sql: get array of numbers "id" column

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
 id idR  name    check
 1  id1  John    true
 2  id1  Abe     false
 3  id2  Ernest  false
 4  id3  Alice   false
 5  id3  Alf     false
 6  id3  Ralf    false
 7  id4  Danny   false
 8  id5  Alex    false
 9  id5  Nicolas false
 10 id7  Dan     true
```

I need to get an array of integers that tell me for each `"idR"` alike than they are.
For example, I would get something like this:

```
2,1,3,1,2,0,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    select idR,count(*) as count_idR from table group by idR;
```

but for idR 6 you want zero than you have to specify condition that till which number you want to get count according to that we can make query, rest the above one give you all present counts.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select idR,count (distinct id )as count from table group by idR;
```